# Insert every array item into Mysql database using react js

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, postman

I fetched my api and inserted the data into array.
And then I tried to insert every item in array into Mysql database.
But execution of code only return 3 items not 20 items(length of array).
My code is below:

```
const label = [];
const calories = [];

const getData = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(
    `https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2?type=public&q=egg&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`
  );
  const data = response.data.hits;

  data.map((item) => {
    label.push(item.recipe.label); //label object in api
    calories.push(item.recipe.calories); //calories object in api
  });

  app.post("/books", (req, res) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
      const q = "INSERT INTO apiData (`name`, `calories`) VALUES (?)";
      var values = [label[i], calories[i]];
      db.query(q, [values], (err, data) => {
        if (err) return res.json(err);
        return res.json("Data created successfully!");
      });
    }
  });
};
getData();
```

I'm using postman to post into mysql.
When I click send button in POST mode, it returns below
[return image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdXmF.png)
If anyone knows what's the problem please let me know

THank you